# Changing between layouts requires refresh to see changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my controller, I've got my `show` action using a different layout (e.g., `foo.html.erb`) than my `application.html.erb`. `foo.html.erb` has styles loading directly in the `<head>`, for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        {styles here}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the controller code for how I'm resolving the layout:

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController
  layout :resolve_layout

  def show
  end

  private
    def resolve_layout
      case action_name
      when 'show'
        'foo'
      else
        'application'
      end
    end
end
```

The problem is, the application seems to cache the templates too heavily, and when I click through to a view that should be using the `show` template, I don't see those `<head>` styles without a refresh.

Am I handling this correctly, or is there a more "rails way" of doing this? What I'm really trying to accomplish here is having styles unique to a particular template only load with that single template. I think this may be an asset pipeline question, but I'm not sure, as I'm still new to Rails.

Comment: Whats your controller code?

Comment: How exactly do you load styles to the head?
Have you tried using <%= yield :head %> in the head section of your application.html and use content_for :head
[as explained here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-content-for)?

Comment: I've added the relevant code from the controller. @Chai - I will read over that and give it a shot later this afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it was an issue with the styles living in the head. I had a relatively simple page, so I was able to move them to be inline styles, and the problem seems to be solved.